# Deleting item from list ( li element), giving index -1. Javascript ( Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension, in which I am adding an item in the list and it has a button to delete the item. 
It performs its function as intended but is giving an error in the extension panel.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
For line :                 li.style.display = "none";
```

Upon adding alert in the function, I see that when any of the delete button is clicked first the intended index is alerted and in some cases, -1 is also alerted.

Code which is adding the item and has the delete functionality as well :

```
  function addItem(value){
    var li = document.createElement("LI");          
    var para = document.createElement("P");    
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");                   // Create a <p> node
    var t = document.createTextNode(value);      // Create a text node

    deleteButton.className = "delete";

    para.appendChild(t); 
    li.appendChild(para);
    li.appendChild(deleteButton);
    textList.appendChild(li); 

    $(".delete").click(function () {
                var index = $(this).index(".delete");
                alert(index); //This alert sometimes gives -1 
                var li = this.parentElement;
                li.style.display = "none";
                removeItem(index);  //This function just removes it from chrome local storage
                $(".delete").eq(index).remove();
            })
    }
```

Code not posted just initializes list and add item upon button click.
What could be the reason for this -1 index being triggered and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're attaching multiple event handlers to the existing `.delete` buttons every time you add a new row.

A better approach is to use a single delegate event handler for them all. Also note that you can make the code more succinct by using jQuery, as you already have a reference to it in the page. Try this:

```js
function addItem(value) { 
  $(textList).append(`<li><p>${value}</p><button class="delete"></button></li>`);
}

jQuery($ => {
  $(textList).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    let $button = $(this);
    removeItem($button.index('.delete'));
    $button.closest('li').remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do this: `$(".delete").click(...`

...you're adding a `click` callback to every delete button that exists at the time you execute that code, *including* the delete buttons *that already exist*, not just the individual delete button you just created.

After you've added three items, for example, the first item's delete button will have three click callbacks, the second will have two click callbacks, and the third will have one.

When you delete the first item, it will smoothly delete once, then twice give you the -1 error, because it has already deleted itself and won't be found.

I think if you change the code like this:

`$(deleteButton).click(...`

...that should fix the problem.

Comment: It did fix the problem. Exactly I saw sometimes -1 popping more than one time in cases.